# Using Google and Twitter OAuth with a React frontend and Node backend w/ PassportJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth, passport.js

I'm currently trying to integrate Google and Twitter OAuth into my site. It currently has a front-end react server that makes api calls to the backend which serves JSON to the front-end. Currently, we're calling /POST requests to the backend and authenticating using local auth strategies with passportJS. Using the Passport.JS Google and Twitter OAuth libraries, they open a new browser and authenticate using the new browser, then calls another callback endpoint which returns the new/returning user object.

Should OAuth responsibility be delegated to my React app? Is there a way to authenticate through my backend service with Oauth?

Also - if I somehow did manage to get this to work, either Google or Twitter OAuth would hit a route that runs a callback. This route is currently in my backend, and there's no way for me to get my backend service to infer a change to my frontend. How should I structure OAuth with a decoupled app?

Comment: Did you find a solution for it?